# Why I can't get the results of intdump with complex numbers

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I need to get the integral of a column over such interval, but the results are strange.

I use the function `intdump`. For example, suppose I have a column of 16 rows and 1 columns, and I need to take the integral and dump `intdump` over 4, which means the results will be of 4 rows and 1 column, but the results are strange.

For example, I have the data:

```
h = [
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.7071 + 0.7071i
  -0.7071 + 0.7071i
  -0.7071 + 0.7071i
   0.7071 + 0.7071i];
```

when I use the command `Y = intdump(h,4);` I get the below results:

```
Y =
       0.0000 + 0.0000i
       0.0000 + 0.0000i
       0.0000 + 0.0000i
       0.0000 + 0.7071i
```

However, the expected results must be like below:

```
Y =
       0.0000 + 0.0000i
       0.0000 + 0.0000i
       0.0000 + 0.0000i
       0.7071 + 0.7071i
```

Please, anyone can support in that issue?

Comment: The first result is correct, what you expect is not. Check with `Y = intdump([real(h) imag(h)],4)` it will confirm the first one.

Comment: First, The first results doesn't have the real part, it just contains the imaginary part. and the command you gave also doesn't give the right results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you didn't understand what [`intdumb`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/intdump.html) does and what are the expected results.

When you ask `Y = intdump(h,4);`, you require performing an averaged integration over each period of 4 samples. In other words, you regroup your data by 4 samples, sum it, then divide the result by 4.

```
0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i
----------------
(0.0000 + 0.0000i) / 4 = 0.0000 + 0.0000i

0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i
----------------
(0.0000 + 0.0000i) / 4 = 0.0000 + 0.0000i

0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i
----------------
(0.0000 + 0.0000i) / 4 = 0.0000 + 0.0000i

0.7071 + 0.7071i
-0.7071 + 0.7071i
-0.7071 + 0.7071i
0.7071 + 0.7071i
----------------
(0.0000 + 2.8284i) / 4 = 0.0000 + 0.7071i
```

So Matlab returns perfect results. I don't why you expect different results, but those are not what `intdump` is supposed to return.

---

Another way to compute this, is to use the propriety of linearity of the integral operator. Indeed you have:

**INTEGRAL(A + iB) = INTEGRAL(A) + i*INTEGRAL(B)**

So in your case, you can separate real and imaginary part of `h`

```
Y_temp = intdump([real(h) imag(h)],4);
Y = Y_temp(:,1)+i*Y_temp(:,2)
```